# Why I can't insert a file into a SharePoint list via code? It goes into exception, seems that the access is denied

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I am very new in **SharePoint** (I am using SharePoint 2013) and I am experiencing a strange problem. This is very strange because in another section of my application it works fine (in another subsite).

So basically into SharePoint I have a **SharePoint list** named **Protocollo**.

My code contains the following lines that add a document (a file) into a subfolder of the previous SharePoint List:

```
internal static int InsertItem(Dictionary<string, object> prot, Documento doc, bool assignVisibility, bool newItem)
{
    int state = 0;
    SPListItem item = null;
    UOR currUOR = null;
    List<UOR> path = new List<UOR>();

    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    string siglaAOO = web.Properties["sigla_aoo"];
    DBConnection dbConfig = ArxeiaProtocollo.Util.ProtUtils.InitializeDBConnection();

    dbConfig.Database = siglaAOO;
    string username = web.CurrentUser.LoginName;

    try
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Protocollo"];
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPFolderCollection folders = list.RootFolder.SubFolders;
        SPFolder annoFolder;
        DateTime dateProt = Convert.ToDateTime(prot["Data protocollo"]);

        try
        {
            annoFolder = folders[dateProt.Year.ToString()];
        }
        catch
        {
            annoFolder = folders.Add(dateProt.Year.ToString());
        }
        SPFolder meseFolder;
        try
        {
            meseFolder = annoFolder.SubFolders[dateProt.Month.ToString("D2")];
        }
        catch
        {
            meseFolder = annoFolder.SubFolders.Add(dateProt.Month.ToString("D2"));
        }
        SPFolder dayFolder;
        try
        {
            dayFolder = meseFolder.SubFolders[dateProt.Day.ToString("D2")];
        }
        catch
        {
            dayFolder = meseFolder.SubFolders.Add(dateProt.Day.ToString("D2"));
        }

        SPFile spFile = dayFolder.Files.Add(doc.Nome, doc.File, true);
        ............................................................
        ............................................................
        ............................................................
}
```

As you can see the previous code retrievce the **Protocollo** list from the current website allowing updates on it by:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Protocollo"];
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
```

Then into this list it creates (it doesn't exist) a gerarcic folders structure for year (annoFolder), month (meseFolder) and day (**dayFolder**).

It works fine, I tried to delete these folder structure from my SharePoint site and performing this method it is created again, infact this is what I obtained:

[image]

As you can see it correctly creates this folder structure into my SharePoint list (named **Protocollo**) into the current website.

Ok finnally my code try to insert a document into the last subfolder (the **dayfolder**) by:

```
SPFile spFile = dayFolder.Files.Add(doc.Nome, doc.File, true);
```

I am passing to the Add() method: the name of the file, the byte array representing the file and the true boolean value.

```
The problem is that performing this line I obtain the following exception that is not providing information:

{Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}
```

Then in my front end it appears a "denied access" popup window.

The strange thing is that another sites in my SharePoint that uses the same code have no problem. Another strange thing is that manually uploading the file into this location of the list it works fine so I think that it should not be a user permission problem.

Some idea? What can I try to do to solve this strange problem?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint codes run using the Application Pool user in IIS not the user that you have logged in to SharePoint, so it is common to get an access denied error even when ***you*** have access. So I would suggest you check the permission for the AppPool account on the Protocollo library. Or you can use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` if you have trust in the user that will run the code.

Beware of the [pitfalls](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3802/when-and-how-to-use-run-with-elevated-privileges-rwep-in-sharepoint/) though.

Here is a sample usage:

```
Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
Guid webId = SPContext.Current.Web.ID;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webId))
        {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
});
```